# Is $\mbox{im }\mbox{cf}$ the class of all cardinals?

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, cardinals

I was traying to define the cofinality $\mbox{cf}$ as a function from the class of all sets to the class of all cardinals, as Kelley does with the function $\mbox{card}$.

Clearly the assignment $A\mapsto \mbox{cf }A$ is well defined, taking for example the definition

$$ \mbox{cf A} = \inf \{\kappa : B\mbox{ is cofinal on } A \mbox{ and } \kappa=\mbox{card }B\} .$$

Now, with AC, is clear that $\mbox{dom }\mbox{cf} =\mathcal U $, the class of all sets, since every sets admits a well-order and then we can talk about cofinal subsets on them.

It is also clear $\mbox{im }\mbox{cf}$ is a subset or subclass of the class of all cardinals. But are they the same?. Since all cardinals $\aleph_\alpha$ are regulars up to $\omega$, both must agree up to $\omega$. For $\aleph_\omega$, I know its cofinality is $\omega$. However, that doesn't proof there is no a set $A$ such that $\mbox{cf }A = \aleph_\omega$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does "$B$ is cofinal on $A$" mean if $A$ is just a set?  Just because a well-ordering exists on $A$ does not magically make "$B$ is cofinal on $A$" meaningful--you have to _choose_ some specific well-ordering, and the definition will get will depend on what well-ordering you chose.

Comment: @EricWofsey: Since the Axiom of Choice holds, every set can be well-ordered. That means there exists at least one order in $A$ to be able to talk about cofinal subsets. I've tried to explain it in my question, but perhaps I've done it wrongly.

Comment: There exists at least one order, but _which_ order are you using?

Comment: Humm... Maybe my answer is horrible but there it goes. I don't mind. I know it is important. I mean, the cofinality of a set depends on the relation you set. For example, with the usual order (which is not a well order), $\mathbb N$ is cofinal in $\mathbb R$, and thus $\mbox{cf }\mathbb R = \aleph_$. However, if you set the well order $\in$, then Wiki says $\mbox{cf }\mathbb R > \aleph_0$. Probably my above answer ''I don't mind'' is horrible, but I don't know enough maths to realize it myself.

Comment: The right way to do this is to talk about the cofinality of a well-ordered set, not just a set.  In other words, you define $cf(A,<)$ if $<$ is a well-ordering on $A$, rather than just $cf(A)$ for a set on its own.

Comment: @Just for finish the chat (otherwise moderators get angry): You're rightbut then the domain of the function becomes very difficult. $\mathcal U$ was simplier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prove for any ordinal that $cf(cf(\alpha))=cf (\alpha)$: any cofinal sequence in $cf(\alpha)$ gives rise to a cofinal sequence in $\alpha$ by composing with the cofinal embedding $cf(\alpha) \rightarrow \alpha$.

Thus if $cf(\alpha) < \alpha$, there can be no way to make $\alpha$ the cofinality of any ordinal.

As an aside, I'm not entirely comfortable with your definition of cofinality on a set without specifying a well-ordering. Under AC every non-empty set has a well-ordering with a maximum element, so if your infinum is taken over all well-orderings on $A$ then it is $1$ for all sets.

Comment: I didin't know the second part of your claim. I mean, as far as I knew, the Axiom of Choice is equvalent to the well-ordering theorem, but I dind't know this well-ordering had a maximal element. According to [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_theorem) the proof of this theorem uses Zermelo's lemma, but in the set of all well ordering defined on subsets of $A$. Sorry, I don't want to be rude, but are you sure the well ordeing theorem afims all set has a maximal element?

Comment: And regarding your answer, very good. Very clear. I know that identity but I had not thought about using it.

Comment: @Dog_69: Given any well-ordering of a (nonempty) set $A$, just pick an element $a\in A$ and define a new ordering which is the same as the old on elements other than $a$ but for which $a$ is the largest element.

Comment: @EricWofsey: Right. So, a useful comment to my question could be: **It's not worth defining cofinality as a function**, right? At least as a fuction over $\mathcal U$, maybe over $\mathbf{Ord}$...

Answer (score 2):

No: Singular cardinals cannot be the cofinality of anything.

If $\alpha$ is singular, then anything that has a cofinal subsequence of length $\alpha$ *also* has a cofinal subsequence of length $\operatorname{cf}\alpha$ -- so $\alpha$ cannot be its cofinality.

Since singular cardinals undoubtedly exist -- $\omega_\omega$ is one -- not all cardinals are cofinalities.